# How to get localPosition of pointer within a VisualElement without a callback

Tags: unity-game-engine, ui-toolkit

I have an issue with the input system that I can't figure out.

I have a VisualElement (using the UI Toolkit), and I need to get the "localPosition" of the pointer on click. (It's going to be a game for touch and mouse so I use pointer.)

I can get the local position using a callback:

```
myVisualElement.RegisterCallback<PointerDownEvent>(OnPointerDown, TrickleDown.TrickleDown);
```

Then in the function:

```
private void OnPointerDown(PointerDownEvent evt)
    {
        pointerLocalPos = evt.localPosition;
    }
```

But I'm also using the new input system for getting the pressed states (started, canceled, etc.):

```
InputManager.inputControls.Draw.Click.started += ctx => Click_started(ctx);
```

**Here's the problem.** I need to get the localPosition within the VisualElement *before* or just at the beginning when "Click.started" is called. But the Click_started() fucntion will always be called before "OnPointerDown" sets the value for the pointer position.  Is there a way to get the localPosition in the "Click_started" function without a callback maybe? Or is there a another of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If delaying the processing is an option, you could try something like this (untested):

```cs
InputManager.inputControls.Draw.Click.started += Click_started;


using System.Threading.Tasks;

async void Click_started()
{
    await Task.Yield();
    // now OnPointerDown should have been called, if it was going to be..

}
```

Comment: That's a solution, but I'd rather avoid this workaround, as I feel like it could cause problems.

Comment: @KeepCool it’s a delay of one “frame”, just enough time for the other processes to run before hand. I did think that you’re delaying the process by one frame,and might that cause an issue, but about a week ago, I was looking through the Unity code for a lot of the InputSystemUIInputModule (off the top of my head) and there were comments from the Unity team about delaying processing by a frame, if I recall correctly, for a very similar reason. I’m not in front of the computer at the moment, so I can’t check to see what mechanism they used.

Comment: Oh ok. Unfortunately, it didn't work. Error: "The body of... cannot be an iterator block because 'void' is not an iterator interface type

Comment: @KeepCool sorry, got that mixed up with coroutines. Luckily I pointed out it was untested! Fixed the code.

Comment: Wow! It worked. I feel like it's not an elegant way to do it, but seems to be the only way. Thanks so much!